# Get a string representation of Days of Week from alphabetic representation in a select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database field which defines the days of operations for a vehicle as below.

Operation_days: 1234567 (1 means Monday, 2 means Tuesday, .... and 7 means Sunday)..

For different vehicles, operations days can be like 134, 12367, 346 (or any combination).

For this given input, how can I get a string representation of this like below.

Input: Operation_days: 1234567
Output: Days: M,T,W,T,F,S,S

I have tried using the stuff operator to select but I am not exactly sure how I can iterate over each field..

I have also tried the CASE WHEN THEN END statement, but there are too many permutations to hard code, so I am thinking of a generic select statement, which can return me the string representation based on any input combination.

Comment: The requirement seems odd. If you get an output of `T,S` how do you know what that was supposed to represent? (was it Tuesday and Saturday? Or Thursday and Sunday?)

Comment: What data type is operation days?

Comment: It's not particularly clear but it would appear you want to translate characters from one thing to another. Maybe look at the suitably named `translate` function? `select Translate('1234567', '1234567', 'MTWTFSS')` It's not clear though how this is of any use, is T Tuesday or Thursday? is TT two tuesdays or a tuesday and a thursday?

Comment: I suppose you could nest a bunch of `REPLACE` functions, then trim off the last comma.

Comment: I'm guessing (or being nice to OP, who knows), the real names that will be used is of such language where there's no ambiguity between initial letters of days or OP will use three-letters versions in the "real" code

Comment: @siggemannen that would indeed make more sense but the OP provides a specific desired result (I think!) so why ask for one thing but expect another :-/

Comment: I find it odd that it one has such a legacy system that there doesn't already exist ways to access this data.  Because surely no one would design a new system that way.

Comment: Leaving aside the usefulness of this, you can either run the string through a recursive CTE and process each character with a case when, or put each possible combination of operation days in a lookup table.

Comment: The real problem here is your table design. You have violated 1NF by shoving multiple values into a single tuple. This is also the reason you are struggling to get the data back out. When a database is designed well, the queries are easy. When it is designed poorly even the most basic queries (like this one) can become extremely difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by numerous comments above, single-letter will not work for this because you cannot distinguish Tuesday from Thursday or Saturday from Sunday. You'll need to use more than one letter, which excludes easy functions such as `translate()`. Here's a solution that uses the `replace()` function, so you can pick the letters that you feel are best for each day. The lengths can vary.

```
create table schedule (
  car_id integer, 
  operation_days varchar(7)
  );

insert into schedule values 
(1, 1234567), 
(2, 134), 
(3, 12367), 
(4, 346);
```

```
select car_id, 
  substring(s_days, 1, (len(s_days)-1)) as car_schedule
from (
select car_id, 
 replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(operation_days, 
  '1', 'M,'), 
  '2', 'T,'), 
  '3', 'W,'),
  '4', 'Th,'), 
  '5', 'F,'), 
  '6', 'Sa,'),
  '7', 'Su,') as s_days
from schedule
  )z
```

| car_id | car_schedule |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | M,T,W,Th,F,Sa,Su |
| 2 | M,W,Th |
| 3 | M,T,W,Sa,Su |
| 4 | W,Th,Sa |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3D0GTiYU)

**UPDATE**

Or as Martin suggested, prefix the days with a comma, which would preclude the need to calculate the length...

```
select car_id, 
  SUBSTRING(
 replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(operation_days, 
  '1', ',M'), 
  '2', ',T'), 
  '3', ',W'),
  '4', ',Th'), 
  '5', ',F'), 
  '6', ',Sa'),
  '7', ',Su'), 2, 8000) as s_days
from schedule
```

Comment: maybe easier to remove leading comma as then don't have to calculate the length https://dbfiddle.uk/c9kltmuJ

Answer (score 2):

Here's some example DDL/DML:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY, OperationDays VARCHAR(7));
INSERT INTO @Table (OperationDays) VALUES
('1357'),('1234567'),('23456');
```

This is really helpful when attempting to answer questions.

As others have pointed out, using `SMTWTFS` isn't a great idea. This has however already been solved many years ago: `NMTWRFS` represents all the days of the week with `N` standing in for Su**n**day, and `R` for Thu**r**sday.

Consider:

```
;WITH days AS (
SELECT ID, OperationDays, SUBSTRING(OperationDays,1,1) AS Chr, 1 AS ChrN
  FROM @Table t
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, OperationDays, SUBSTRING(OperationDays,ChrN+1,1), ChrN+1
  FROM days
 WHERE chr < LEN(OperationDays)
)

SELECT ID, STRING_AGG(DayV,',') AS CarSchedule
  FROM days d
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DayI, DayV FROM (VALUES (1,'N'),(2,'M'),(3,'T'),(4,'W'),(5,'R'),(6,'F'),(7,'S')) a(DayI, DayV)) a
      ON d.Chr = a.DayI
 GROUP BY ID;
```

Assuming you have access to `STRING_AGG`. This also has the advantage of making  the substituted days rows in a table (or a values statement in this case).

| ID | CarSchedule |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | N,T,R |
| 2 | N,M,T,W,R,F,S |
| 3 | M,T,W,R |

Answer (score 1):

Another option to split the day numbers into rows (where they should be), joining to a mapping table expression and then re-aggregating, obviously the mapped day value can be anything you choose:

```
/*Populate some test data*/
select * into t 
from(values 
    (1, '1234567'), 
    (2, '134'), 
    (3, '12367'), 
    (4, '346'))v(VehicleId, Operation_days)

select VehicleId, String_Agg(v.dayval, ',')
from t
join(values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7))n(n) on n <= Len(Operation_days)
cross apply(values(Substring(Operation_days, n, 1)))d(daynum)
join(values('1', 'Mon'),('2', 'Tue'),('3', 'Wed'),('4', 'Thu'),
           ('5', 'Fri'),('6', 'Sat'),('7', 'Sun')
    )v(daynum, dayval) on v.daynum = d.daynum
group by VehicleId;
```

See a [demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qi9RUhNX)